# Using clear:both to make div full height of content?

Tags: html, css

Do you need to use something like `<div style="clear:both">&nbsp;</div>` after any floating content to make sure your div goes the full height of your content or is there any easier way of doing this?

Below is the code im currently using

HTML

```
<div class="socialmedia">
<h2>Stay Connected</h2>
<ul>
<li><img src="images/twitter.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Twitter" /></li>
<li><img src="images/googleplus.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Google Plus" /></li>
<li><img src="images/behance.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Behance" /></li>
<li><img src="images/dribble.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Dribble" /></li>
<li><img src="images/pinterest.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Pintrest" /></li>
<li><img src="images/email.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Email" /></li>
</ul>
<div style="clear:both">&nbsp;</div>
</div><!-- close social media -->
```

CSS

```
 .socialmedia {
width:960px;
background-color:#C69;

 }

 .socialmedia ul {
margin:0;
padding:0;
clear:both;
}


 .socialmedia ul li {
float:left;
list-style:none;
margin-right:20px;
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can add overflow:auto to your container DIV.

Answer (score 4):

You could give `.socialmedia` a style of `overflow:hidden` and remove the clearing div.

Answer (score 1):

Use `li { display: inline-block; }` - gives you flexibility as far as centering your list, and doesn't require any float-clearing methods.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/NKzm2/

*Note that in the fiddle I added `ul { font-size: 0; }` - This is to negate the fact that inline elements cause whitespace in the markup to display if their font-size is non-zero.*

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
.socialmedia ul:after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
```